# Interface field should have type of the class that implements that interface - typescript

Tags: typescript, types, interface, typing

I am wondering if this is achievable in Typescript.

```
interface Pine {

    child : <The class that implements this interface>
}

class Vine implements Pine {

    child : Vine // this is enforced to be Vine, rather than any object that implements Pine.
}
```

I know from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8407882/enforcing-return-type-for-an-class-that-implements-an-interface) that you cannot do it in Java, but what about TS? I have looked up tslang doc without fruition.

Comment: I think polymprphic this is as close as you will get. It's not exactly waht you want because `Vine` could be subclassed and then `child` will be of the subclass type: https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgAqhQbwFDef5BAC2ABsATZALmTBIGdsBfXBUue+5ANQ2WAC2AB1IQBEcF3QgsuAoRIUAhDTrAuzIA

Answer (score 0):

You can use Generics.
e.g. :

```
interface Base<T> {
    child: T;
}

class Derived implements Base<string> {
    child: string;
} 

class Derived2 implements Base<number> {
    child: number;
}
```

Comment: this is not what i want. i want the child in Derived to have type Derived and child in Derived2 to have Derived2, without allowing for the derived classes themselves choosing which to put into the generics. Your answer would be effectively the same without using the generics at all.

Comment: Did you mean:

interface Base<T> {
    child: T;
}

class Derived implements Base<Derived> {
    child: Derived;
} 

class Derived2 implements Base<Derived2> {
    child: Derived2;
}

Comment: You see, if the child is enforced to be Derived2 *only after specifying Derived2 in the generic field*, that would defeat the purpose. What i need is that upon the implementation of Pine, any vine's child is Vine and is enforced to be Vine, *without* referencing Vine anywhere else.